# Problema al asignar roles en método AddToRoleAsync

Tags: asp.net-core

Estoy tratando de agregar roles a un usuario "X" pero el visual me marca el siguiente error

no se puede convertir de 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' a 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'

Esto me sucede al tratar de buscar al usuario en base al id

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       var userid = model.User;
       _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(_userManager.FindByIdAsync(userid), 
        model.RoleName);
    }
```

¿alguien sabe a que se deba?

Estoy trabajando con ASP.Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucioné

La variable user debía traerla directa del modelo y no estaba haciendol el método como tipo asincrono. Dejo el código que me solucionó el problema

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(AddRoleToUserModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.User);
        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, model.RoleName);
    }
    return View();
}
```